# Where are the device file kept for each keyboard console shell on a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, keyboard, system

I am trying to find where the keyboard is kept on a linux system?

Is it under /dev/input?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to accomplish? "each shell" sounds like a PTY issue. And don't think of "the keyboard", as you can plug in many keyboards (and mice).

Comment: I was able to find it out. What i was looking for was /dev/pts but thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably working with terminal in Linux, so that's why you are looking for terminal device driver. I think these two links are a good answer for you... explaining the difference between TTY, PTY & PTS.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/difference-between-pts-and-tty
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Text-Terminal-HOWTO-7.html

But to add, deciding which one is you choice depends on the way you are connected to Linux machine ... this link helps on this issue:

[what is the difference between tty and vty in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847354/what-is-the-difference-between-tty-and-vty-in-linux)

Cheers