# what is the difference between tty and vty in linux

Tags: linux

Can anyone explain me the difference between vty and tty ?

I am getting the following when i execute tty .

```
[sce@..]# tty
/dev/pts/135
```

what is /dev/pts/135 here ?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; try posting at superuser.com

Comment: and please google, before:
http://www.techexams.net/forums/ccna-ccent/14950-line-tty-vty-differences.html

Answer (score 7):

TTY Definition:
Teletypewriter originally and now also means any terminal on Linux/Unix systems. It also means any serial port on Unix/Linux systems.

PTS Definition:
Stands for pseudo terminal slave.

The difference between TTY and PTS is the type of connection to the computer. TTY ports are direct connections to the computer such as a keyboard/mouse or a serial connection to the device. PTS connections are SSH connections or telnet connections. All of these connections can connect to a shell which will allow you to issue commands to the computer.

Virtual teletype (VTY) is a command line interface (CLI) created in a router and used to facilitate a connection to the daemon via Telnet, a network protocol used in local area networks. To connect to a VTY, users must present a valid password.

Answer (score 0):

PTS is a pseudo terminal - when you for ex. login via SSH session or launch a session that is emulating terminal (like xterm, konsole) a pts device is being launched. TTY type is a native one - for example when you go to session on runlevel without graphics.